# Is it possible to create conditional logic for a link inside html page

Tags: html, hyperlink, conditional-statements, logic

Specifically I would like the home link to return them to a landing page if they first landed on that landing page. So lets say they land on a city landing page, then they visit other pages on the site I would like if they hit the home page link on those pages to be sent back to the city landing page. Is this possible? If so please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t really understand what you want but you can create logics in php. Use sessions to save wether or not a user visited the site. If you want more information or a better answer write names for the pages and write exactly what the client does and what changes html should have

## Edit

It´s not possible in html. You set a php session (for example $_SESSION['site']) to the URL of the site you want the user to return to. You got to use a server and php so you have to save a.html as a.php. Download for example xampp and put your files into the htdocs folder. Start the Apache server.

Lets say you have the follownig:

```
htdocs/
  |-  index.php
  |-  a.php
  |-  b.php
```

Add this to the beginning of index.php. This will return the user to the site you put into $_SESSION['site']:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    
    if (isset($_SESSION['site'])) {
        header('Location: '.$_SESSION['site']);
        exit();
    }
 ?>
```

This is how you set the session. For example in page b.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['site'] = '/b.php';
 ?>
```

or in a.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['site'] = '/a.php';
 ?>
```

If you want to delete the session you can for example make a site (htdocs/stop-session.php) with this code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: /');
    exit();
 ?>
```

Another way is JS but thats far more complicated in my eyes. You could use coockies there.

I hope it helps. If you want any changes comment

Comment: I have an html website, I would like to have a conditional logic that if someone lands on page a.html that when they navigate away if they hit home it takes them back to a.html instead of index.html if they land on b.html to return to it and so on.